# Declaring a global string variable/welcome message in Java

Tags: java, global

I wanted to declare a global variable of string type, because i have some more integer variable which i declared as global and they ask for value before welcome message. I tried to use JOptionPane to show the welcome message, after trying to convert using integer.ParseInt method, but for some reason its not working. any solution

I tried to declare this as global variable by writing:

```
private static int welcome = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    "Welcome to depreciation calculation"));
```

but this code isn't working, though similar code is working for other variables, but in global variable its creating problem. I just want to know, how it can be done.

Comment: Paste the code please.

Comment: @FaisalUddin Update your question, don't comment !

Comment: What sort of code is this : `private static int welcome Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to depreciation calculation"))` ?

Answer (score 0):

That is a compilation error. [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) needs a `String` argument, you are passing `void`. [showMessageDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object%29) returns a void. This will never work.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome to depreciation"));
```

Comment: i have used this in other part of my codes, but only problem occurs when i try to use it for global variable